# object not is not JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I am trying to load data from a database into a html page. basically when a user access their profile and clicks on "Purchase History" it should query the database and display all the products the user has purchased.

I am trying to do this using ajax and json, but i get an error:

```
TypeError: <gluon.dal.Field object at 0x091CCD90> is not JSON serializable
```

Below is the code:

```
def prodHistoryJson():
    productName = db.sale.title
    productCost = db.sale.price
    prodShipAdd = db.sale.shipping_address
    prodShipCity = db.sale.shipping_city
    prodShipState = db.sale.shipping_state
    prodShipZipCode = db.sale.shipping_zip_code

    myproducts = {'prodName':productName, 
                  'cost':productCost, 
                  'shipAdd':prodShipAdd, 
                  'shipCity':prodShipCity,
                  'shipState':prodShipState, 
                  'shipZipCode':prodShipZipCode}

    import  gluon.contrib.simplejson as json
    returnData = json.dumps(myproducts)

return returnData
```

below is the jquery:

```
$.ajax( {
        url:'/suzannecollins/onlineStore/prodHistoryJson',
        data: { message: "Your products purchase history is listed below" },
        success: function(msg) {

           try {
                myproducts=JSON.parse(msg);
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(" error");
            }
            // place returned value in the DOM
            $('#returnData').html(myproducts.title + myproducts.price + myproducts.shipping_address
             + myproduct.shipping_state + myproducts.shipping_city + myproducts.shipping_zip_code);
    }
});
```

what am i doing wrong?
I can get this all to work if i just do this in a simpler way where a user hits the purchase_History button and it queries the database and displays the products purchased. How do i do the same thing with the code above?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. `gluon.dal.Field` can not be serialized to JSON.

Comment: It seems like `db.sale.title` etc. are not strings you hope for, but rather the field descriptors. How are you getting those?

Comment: Side note: remove the `try-catch` in your AJAX code. It's better to see mistakes due to the page not loading correctly, rather than silently sweeping them to the console where you'll never see them. As it's structured right now, your code might throw an exception yet still try to modify the page, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: agreed with @musical_coder, moving answer to comment: Would be interesting to see more of the stack trace and the declaration of you db fields. Some db fields are not serializable (like db.GeoPt, dates, db.Key, etc) directly, and you need to do it 'manually'. I had the same problem and solved it by using this answer.

Comment: @Amadan, they are defined in the sale table.
musical_coder, right now i am just trying to load raw data using json, i have however removed the try catch from the code as requested.

Comment: No - the JavaScript variables you're using are not defined in the sale table, they're defined somewhere in JavaScript. The *values you are hoping to get* are in the sale table. My hypothesis, knowing nothing of web2py, is that one of them snuck by into the other. If you do a `console.dir(db.sale.title)`, do you get a string, or do you get an object with a bunch of different stuff including the field descriptor? Because only the string (and other primitive values) should go into JSON. (and hashes and arrays obviously, but you shouldn't expect to get those from a database.)

Comment: @Amadan i get an error when i do a console.dir(db.sale.title) stating db is not defined. not the brightest at coding, still trying to get my head around it.

Comment: Ouch, I'm an idiot, that relevant piece of code is in Python. So go in there and print `db.sale.title.__class__.__name__` and I bet it won't show "str". I just took a look at web2py, and it seems that what you want is something like `db.sale(id).title`, to get a specific row, or using `db(db.sale).select(...)` or something similar to get at the actual values in the database.

Comment: @Amadan just for testing purposes, i tired what you suggested with the products table, where the title field is of type string... i did a query on it to display title for only one product, 
requestData = db(db.products.id == '1').select(db.products.title)
i still end up getting the same error ... is Not JSON serializable

Comment: one of my other group mate's is also trying to perform the same action as me and it's working fine for him.. his function is:
def userjson():
    """
    Return welcome string
    """
    myobject = {'name':auth.user.first_name, 'greet': 'Welcome to your online store, ' }
    import  gluon.contrib.simplejson as json
    welcome = json.dumps(myobject)
    return welcome

the result shows up as
{"name": "John", "greet": "Welcome to your online store, "}

Comment: The result of the `select` is a collection of rows. You are still having problems accessing the correct value; and the important thing is, in your friend's code, where is `auth` coming from.

Comment: yeah i am using the most simplest and the most restrictive query where it will only display one row but doesn't seem to be working.
and web2py offers default auth.users table so he is using that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40433/discussion-between-thenoob-and-amadan)

Answer (score 0):

so thanks to @Amadan last night, we finally figured out how to query the database using json and serialize the python objects to display the results...

```
def pruchaseHistoryJson():
    if auth.user:
        rows = db(db.sale.auth_id == auth.user.id
                 ).select(db.sale.title, 
                          db.sale.price,
                          db.sale.shipping_address,
                          db.sale.shipping_state,
                          db.sale.shipping_city,
                          db.sale.shipping_zip_code)
    else:
        redirect(URL('default', 'user/login'))

import  gluon.contrib.simplejson as json
prodHistory = json.dumps([{'name': i.title, 
                           'prodValue':i.price,
                           'shipAdd':i.shipping_address,
                           'shipCity':i.shipping_city,
                           'shipState':i.shipping_state,
                           'shipCode':i.shipping_zip_code} for i in rows])
return prodHistory
```

this code works fine and displays the results as expected, now back to the writing up the jquery function for this.